# como obtener registros de mysql que compraron hace un mes pero no este mes?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

estoy trabajando en una consulta de mysql y quiero traer los clientes que compraron hace un mes pero no han comprado este mes tengo este codigo para traer a los que compraron hace un mes pero no se como compararlos para saber si no han comprado este mes

```
select c.* 
from cliente as c 
inner join (SELECT DISTINCT * 
            FROM pedidounhesa 
            WHERE MONTH(fecha_emision) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
            AND YEAR(fecha_emision) = YEAR(NOW()) 
            ORDER BY fecha_emision DESC) as idC on idC.idCliente = c.idCliente ;
```

Comment: con un not in con los clientes que compraron este mes ;)

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras la estructura de tus tablas

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar usar DISTINCT, puedes usar IN o EXISTS, así como la negación de los mismos.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM cliente as c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  * 
            FROM pedidounhesa as p
            WHERE MONTH(fecha_emision) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
            AND YEAR(fecha_emision) = YEAR(NOW())
            AND p.idCliente  = c.idCliente ) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * 
            FROM pedidounhesa as p
            WHERE MONTH(fecha_emision) = MONTH(NOW()) 
            AND YEAR(fecha_emision) = YEAR(NOW())
            AND p.idCliente  = c.idCliente );
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo resolví

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle al +1, es la forma "oficial" de decir Gracias! en Stack Overflow en español, además haces que el contenido perdure y pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.